# Should Optional change the state of the object it contains?

Tags: java-8

Should an [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) class change the state of the object that it holds? Or every intermediate operation that returns a stream should never change the mutability of the object?
Example:

```
Optional.ofNullable(repository.gePersonById(id))
    .ifPresent(person -> person.setAge(25));
```

Does the same principle apply when it contains an instance variable. E.g

```
Optional.ofNullable(this.person)
    .ifPresent(person -> person.setAge(25));
```

Comment: This makes my skin crawl a little - so I would say, on a gut feeling, no. Can't tell you why. I think it might be the combination of functional paradigms and mutable state.

Comment: `Optional` does *not* make an object immutable, it just adds the option of being absent. Further, there is no use case for `ifPresent` without a side-effect, which makes it standing out against, e.g. `map` or `filter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good question! I think the answer is a matter of choice. My answer would be NO.

The object of an Optional, from the docs:

> A container object which may or may not contain a non-null value. If a value is present, isPresent() will return true and get() will return the value.

So it shouldn't really do more than that :)

But check out Raoul-Gabriel Urma's doc on using Optionals: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html

Here he uses the optional and does something with it if present

```
Optional<Soundcard> soundcard = ...;
soundcard.ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

just like you do in your first piece of code.

But using Optional for checking instance variables just seems a little ... dirty.

Answer (score 1):

Given how much care is taken to document semantic constraints in apis such as `Stream` and `Comparator`, I would take the absence of such constraints in `Optional` as tacit permission to do whatever you want. The only caution it gives is to avoid counting on synchronization or == and such on the Optional since it is an immutable value type and many operations, like `filter` and `map` create new objects rather than modifying the existing one.