# Iterate over list and modify elements with Java streams/optional

Tags: java

I have say a list of Person. I have to iterate over this list to find the person with id X, if found, I have to update some attribute on the person:

```
    persons.stream()
            .filter(person -> "A11".equals(person.getId()))
            .findAny()
            .map(person -> {
                person.setSomeField("some-value");
                return person;
            });
```

This code snippet is working for me, bu I'm not sure it's clear enough what this is trying to achieve, I'm using that .map whose return value I don't really need so I was wondering if there's a better way to do this?

Comment: Why not `forEach`?

Comment: Well, if you mind, what you're doing isn't good practice. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57591037/is-it-ok-for-optionalmap-to-change-the-state-of-the-input-parameter-to-the-func
 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/36914014/17949945

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple solution to find all the person with some given id will be.
Foreach them set the field.

```
persons.stream().filter(p -> "id".equalsIgnoreCase(p.getId())).forEach(person ->
            person.setSomeField("some-value"));
```

Comment: The downside: `.filter(...)` will be executed for all users, even when the right one was already found and patched.

Comment: I think you were mentioning about for each. Yeah like if the there are multiple users with same id then there will be multiple iteration. But still the complexity should be O(N). As the search is also a linear search.

Comment: There is no multiple iteration. You will always iterate over the whole list and calculate the lambda for each element in the list. Even when the first element match, you will iterate over all other elements. There is no `break`-condition. The `.findAny()` on the other hand, will stop after the first user was found.

Answer (score 0):

In case you know that there is only one person with the id, and you want to take advantage of the performance benefit of `findAny()`, an alternative would be:

```java
persons.stream()
  .filter(person -> "A11".equals(person.getId()))
  .findAny()
  .ifPresent(person -> person.setSomeField("some-value"));
```